# Fitting a image on a screen to avoid scroll

Tags: html, css, image, scroll, position

So I'm in the process of finishing my first website in Dreamweaver. I just want to know how can achive that my logo fits the screen without scroll. Because it looks ok on my screen but on a larger sceen the image gets too big and we would have to scroll. Thank you for all your anwsers in advance.

Image size : width: 7,24
             hight: 7,17

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="css1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Matic Toni</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="logo">
        <a href="projects.html">
          <img src="lg.png" width="40%" alt="" />
        </a>
  </div>
  <footer>copyright 2016 maticoni</footer>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";
div {
text-align: center;
padding-bottom: 30px;
}
body {
/* background-image: url(background.jpg);
background-sizce: cover; */
background-color: #F6F6F6;
}

.logo {
padding-top:3%;
}

footer {
font-family:"Proxima";
clear: both;
color: black;
font-size: 100%;
margin-top: 5%;
margin-right: 5%;
margin-left: 5%;
text-align: center;
}

li a img {
padding-top: 3%;
}

@font-face {
font-family: Proxima;
src: url(Fonts/Proxima_Regular.otf);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean vertical or horizontal?

Answer (score 0):

Set a max-width for your img.logo. This will also keep it from getting pixelated at larger screen sizes.